# Print two pages on one sheet in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

Can Microsoft Word print two pages per sheet?

[image: Visualization]

There is a "2 Pages Per Sheet" setting in the print dialog but I'm struggling to set the other parameters (page size, paper size, orientation) properly.

I can get a A4 landscape sheet with two landscape A6 pages in it, but I can't actually get a A4 portrait sheet with two landscape A5 pages in it.

I'm using Office 2016.

Comment: If you use 2 pages per sheet, and just use A4, it should automatically do what you suggest. Just that setting should set everything required automatically, and you should not set anything else.

Comment: @LPChip Where would I set the A4? The "Settings" in the print dialog seem to be per page, which is set to A5 landscape. Should I change the size of all pages to A4 before printing?

Comment: Yes. You set the page setting to what you are going to print to, which is an A4 page in portrait orientation, but then tick the 2 pages per sheet option, and it will then automatically shrink 2 pages to A5 and rotate them so they become A5 portrait in landscape orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Microsoft Word is very much capable of this because it is the printer who is actually doing all the work.

All you do is specify what the paper itself is normally as if you print one page to a paper, and then tick the 2 pages per sheet option.

So you set it as A4 paper, in portrait orientation, and then tick the 2 pages per sheet option.

The printer will now automatically rotate the 2 pages and scale them down to A5. They'll become A5 portrait, but rotated in landscape orientation.

Some printers have more options to deal with this, and some printers don't have this option at all. It does depend on what driver is used. A universal printing driver may not feature this while the full version of the driver specifically for that printer may. Or otherwise, the universal printing driver may just have the 2 pages check, where the full version can do 4 pages, rotate them, etc...